# git reset --hard after evey push

Tags: git

I'm trying to push all commit from my local development envrionment to remote production repository (digitalocean). I have to `git reset --hard`  on remote after every push for the changes to be applied. What is possibly happening and how can I avoid doing this ?

Comment: I suspect your remote repo is not bare. The Git way is to push to a bare repo, trigger a `post-receive` or `post-update` hook that goes to the non-bare repo and pulls.

Comment: Git's not a deployment server. You're not the first to notice it's awfully close, but the remote repo's owner has complete control of its work tree. If that repo's yours, set up hooks to respond however you like.